# Insertion sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have tested this code and it yields the expected outputs, but I want to verify if I have applied insertion sort algorithm correctly or not.

```
 import java.util.*;
public class InsertionSort 
{
    static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = temp; 
    }

    static void sorter(int arr[])
    {

        int hole; 
        int n = arr.length; 
        if(n>=2)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i<n ; i++)
            { 
                hole = i;
                inner:
                for(int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)
                {
                    if(arr[j]> arr[hole])
                    {
                        swap(arr, j, hole);
                        hole = j; 
                    }
                    else
                        break inner; 
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to ascertain correctness or Elegance?  Correctness can be found by tests.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase. `Arr` should be `arr`.

Comment: You can check for such answers online https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Comment: @Sid Correctness, Have I correctly used the concept of insertion sort?

Comment: You can minimize you Code by using sorting method
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/
this can help u out

Comment: It's correct, but it's far from good code. There is no need for `n` as intermediate variable, `if (n>=2)` is redundant, because it will just loop once in this case. The label `inner` is redundant in this case. And in general, if you ever feel you need to use a label in Java, you should restructure your code. And, finally, printing the result should not be done in the sort method.

Comment: You probably meant `System.err.println()`. Messages, like for example debug statements, should be printed to `System.err`, not `System.out`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Labeled loops

You say

> ```
>                         break inner;
> ```

But that's not necessary.  The `inner` loop is already the innermost loop.  You could just say `break;`.

And frankly, you could have just said

```
                for (int j = i-1; j >= 0 && arr[j] > arr[hole]; j--)
```

No `break` or internal `if` needed.

But that's not the question you really wanted answered.

#### Insertion sort?

It's similar to an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).  Your insertion method is a bit odd though.  Normally insertion sort would find the insertion point and then move the elements after that.  You're bubbling the current value forward.

Consider

```
int j = i - 1;
while (j >= 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[i]) {
    j--;
}

int temp = numbers[i];
for (int k = i; k > j; k--) {
    numbers[k] = numbers[k - 1];
}

numbers[j] = temp;
```

That does about half as many array assignments as your method.

#### Naming

I prefer a descriptive name like `numbers` to a generic abbreviation like `arr`.  At minimum, it should be `array`.  But I prefer `numbers`.

> ```
>     static void sorter(int arr[])
> ```

As a general rule, we name classes and objects with noun names.  Methods get verb names.  So

```
    static void sort(int[] numbers) {
```

In Java, we also normally write arrays as `int[] name` not `int name[]`.

You could name the class

```
class InsertionSorter {
```

Although in this case `InsertionSort` can be used as a noun.

#### Wildcard imports

```
import java.util.*;
```

The general policy is to import one class at a time, not a wildcard group.  That's especially true here, since it's not clear that you are using any `java.util` classes.

#### Mixing logic and display

It's generally agreed that it is better to return the data and display it separately.  Since you are sorting in place, that could just look like

```
InsertionSort.sort(numbers);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

#### Declare at initialization

You have

> ```
>                 hole = i;
> ```

You could do

```
                int hole = i;
```

It's generally considered best practice to declare variables as late as possible.  You don't use `hole` outside the loop or across iterations, so there's no need to declare it outside the loop.

#### Redundant logic

> ```
>         if(n>=2)
>         {
>             for(int i = 1; i<n ; i++)
> ```

If `n` is 1 or less then `1 < n` will be false and it won't enter the loop.

And you don't need `n`.  You can just say `numbers.length` whenever you need that value.

#### Standard methods

You could also replace these two loops with Java standard methods.

```
        int insertionPoint = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, 0, i, numbers[i]);
        if (insertionPoint < 0) {
            insertionPoint = -insertionPoint - 1;
        }

        int temp = numbers[i];
        System.arraycopy(numbers, insertionPoint, numbers, insertionPoint + 1, i - insertionPoint);
        numbers[insertionPoint] = temp;
```

Of course, it's possible that you were trying to avoid standard methods.  After all, `Arrays.sort` would solve this problem without additional coding.